# Update one table only after checking the values of another table

Tags: mysql

i wonder if someone could help me out with this problem.
I'd like to update the column "result" in TABLE1 SET "1" when all to the ID(TABLE1) belonging tab1ID-values have in column result the value 1.
The ID in table1 are in relationship with tab1ID in table2. Hope this will make it clear:

Table1:

```
id | result |
1  |  null  |       
2  |  null  |      
3  |  null  |
```

Table2:

```
id | tab1ID | result |
1  |    1   |   1    
2  |    1   |   0   
3  |    1   |   1    
4  |    2   |   1   
5  |    2   |   1    
6  |    2   |   1      
7  |    3   |   0   
8  |    3   |   1   
9  |    3   |   1
```

The UPDATE-Satement should now UPDATE TABLE1 like this:

Table1:

```
id | result |
1  |    0   |       
2  |    1   |      
3  |    0   |
```

result at ID2 is 1 now, because all the belonging tab1ID (2) rows in table2 have the result-value 1

How can i do this with one update-statement?

Answer (score 2):

This query assumes that the values for `Table2.Result` are only `1` and `0`.

```
UPDATE  table1 a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  tab1ID, COUNT(*) = SUM(result) result
            FROM    table2
            GROUP   BY tab1ID
        ) b ON a.ID = b.tab1ID
SET     a.result = b.result
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/224ca/1)

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. This works fine! But initially Table2.Result = NULL. And with your solution this means, that Table1.result will be 0, if one of the Teble2.results is NULL. Sorry, i should have mentioned it before.. My bad..

Comment: so is `NULL` counted or not? based on your given example, if there is an additional record `10  |    2   |   NULL`, is the value of `2` in `table 1` `1` or `0`?

Comment: in that case, i would like not to update table1. i only would like to update table1 if all of table 2 results are 1 or 0. maybe, thats not possible with pure mysql, and i first have to check with php..

Comment: YEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHH !!! Thats it! GREAT! Thanks alot for your help. You just made my day!:-)

Comment: hmmm.. i tried that fiddle again, and table1 is updated with 0. as long as there is a NULL in result.table2, result.table1 should remain NULL.. is that possible?